# Український відповідник до гостелу

Tags: іншомовні-слова

На сайті [Slovotvir](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/khostel) на голосуванні лиш два варіанти: **гостель** і **гуртожиток**, до всього там шукають відповідник до **хостелу** через **х**.

Що можна дібрати або створити нове на позначення гостелу? Чи хай лишається запозиченням?

Пояснення слова з [вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB):

> тимчасове житло економ-класу для туристів, орієнтоване в основному на
>   молодь, головна відмінність якого від готелю — плата за місце, а не за
>   номер.

Міні-готель не годиться, бо тут особливість не в тому, що воно міні, а в тому, що платиш за койку.

Answer (score 2):

На сайті [Glosbe](https://uk.glosbe.com/en/uk/hostel) пропонують:

> **hostel - гостел, хостел, гуртожиток**.

Далі в [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/ghurtozhytok) щодо слова ***гуртожиток*** пише:

> **ГУРТО́ЖИТОК**, тку, чол. Приміщення для спільного проживання осіб, перев. тих, що працюють на одному підприємстві або вчаться в одному навчальному закладі.

Тобто слово **гуртожиток** не зовсім відповідає семантиці слова **хостел**. Спільність хіба в тому, що оплата за ліжко-місце, однак тут різна мета перебування (гуртожиток - спільність заняття, хостел - здебільшого кожен індивідуально).

Оскільки у [географічному словнику](http://ukr-tur.narod.ru/dovidnyk/slovnykh/h1/hostel.htm) читаємо:

> **ХОСТЕЛ** - **різновид готелів** з невеликим набором послуг, ***дешевий молодіжний готель на зразок гуртожитку***.

То, на мою думку, **найкраще** залишити саме слово іншомовного походження **гостел / хостел**, адже воно найкраще відображає семантику. Поки що відповідника, який би найвдаліше і якнайкраще підходив, не знайшла.

Answer (score 1):

Завітав на форум [Словник.нет](http://forum.slovnyk.ua/index.php?showtopic=2842), там пропонують такі варіанти:

[Постоянка](http://sum.in.ua/s/postojanka) (судячи із прикладу, що поданий в СУМі - це не найкращий варіант)

Вітальниця (однак такого слова немає в СУМі)

[Нічліг](http://sum.in.ua/s/nichligh)

[Нічліжка](http://sum.in.ua/s/nichlizhka)

Нічліжок

А в обговореннях на українській [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0:Raider/%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB_(19.04.2010%E2%80%9421.04.2010)) також пропонують варіант "туристичний гуртожиток".